# Jetty.xml import local class

Tags: java, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a web-app that i run through **Maven Jetty** plugin.

I configure it using a jetty.xml file. My problem comes when i want to set a custom authenticator that i have created in the WebAppContext. The XML config looks like below:

```
<New id="webAppContext" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="copyWebDir">true</Set>
    <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
    </Set>
    <Get name="securityHandler">
        <Set name="authenticator">
            <New class="MY_CUSTOM_AUTHENTICATOR">
            </New>
        </Set>
    </Get>
</New>
```

When i run the above i get a `ClassNotFoundException` for "MY_CUSTOM_AUTHENTICATOR" class. I have to add that the class exists in the same maven project that i launch Jetty from.

Is there an "import" statement that i have to do in order for Jetty to load my class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need to have your authenticator in an artifact that is then declared as a dependency of the jetty maven plugin itself.  With classloader isolation in play the authenticator is probably in your webapp where the security handler does not have visibility.

Comment: Jesse thanks for your comment. I actually added the maven project itself as a dependency to the maven jetty plugin and it loaded the class. Thank you.